# Error: Could not find or load main class sample.Main when creating JavaFX project on IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx

I am using IntelliJ and I am trying to learn some JavaFX after covering some parts of Java. I am trying to create a simple HelloWorld application first. When I create a new project, it creates some things automatically, but there are errors and I can't run it:

> ```
> Error: Could not find or load main class sample.Main
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
> Process finished with exit code 1
> ```

What can I do to fix it? I tried to update IntelliJ and to update to JDK 12 and I am still getting this error.

Comment: Does https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Intellij help?

Comment: It all depends on how you tried to create the application file.

Comment: Hi Slaw, I tried it now, it works, but I need to do this process in every time I am starting a new JavaFX project. Is there any way to apply it to be automatic every time I create a new project?

Comment: IntelliJ has project templates which might offer a solution, but I have no idea how they work so I can't provide better help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JavaFx 11 12 or 13 then you have to import the jar files inside the lib folder of the specified javafx folder.Go to configure -> Structure for New Projects-> under the section of Platform settings go to Global Libraries hit the + sign and then browse to the lib folder of your javafx installation.Then you select all the files inside the lib folder and add them except the "src.zip" and name the library something like "Java Fx" or whatever you want.Afterwards you normally create a javafx project and you right click the project folder and go to module settings.Go again to the global libraries right click and add this library to the module.Now you can compile the code and it runs.